How to redirect user to message in channel from bot chat - telegraf
I need to display a url which will redirect users to a message in a channel. It works on iPhone, but not on androids showing this error message - account does not exist
This is the line of code:
await ctx.reply(https://t.me/${process.env.CHANNEL_ID}/${messageId});

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
